# RPM-GPG-KEY Error While Installing Oracle Database 11gr2 on CENTOS 7

Tags: database, centos-7, oracle-linux, oracle-11g

I am Trying to install Oracle Database 11gr2 in CENTOS 7.For installation process I am following this procedure https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-db-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-7

After downloading and unzipping both the package from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linx8664soft-100572.html I am running below command to start installing.

```
yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall
```

after processing for few moment I am getting below error.

> warning:
>   /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/ol7_UEKR3/packages/kernel-uek-firmware-3.8.13-118.6.1.el7uek.noarch.rpm:
>   Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY Retrieving key
>   from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
>
> GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file
>   /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle"

How can I resolve above error and proceed to next step of installation?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on Oracle Linux 7 resolved by changing `gpgcheck=0` in `.repo` file.

For example

**/etc/yum.repos.d/ol7.repo**

```
[ol7_latest]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever Latest ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Get Oracle Linux 7 repository files from below.
[repo archive files](https://github.com/esmaeelE/SysAdmin/blob/main/RHEL/repo/oraclelinux_7.tar.gz)

Put them to `/etc/yum.repos.d` and then Run `yum update`.

Answer (score -2):

Install the Oracle prerequisite packages using the command: "yum install --nogpgcheck ..." and then disable the public-yum-ol7.repo repository

Comment: Wouldn't that disable updates from what looks like a common/primary repo (with nothing to do with oracle from what I can tell), and wouldn't it be better to actually *make sure* the keys are actually installed?